# DBAPI Error; SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected when running docker image

Tags: python, docker, amazon-redshift, psycopg2, python-db-api

I am trying to deploy a python app that filters my database on Redshift then inserts the aggregated rows into a new table. The insert works fine from the python script but when running the docker image it returns **sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected**.

According to the Sqlalchemy docs: *This error is a DBAPI Error and originates from the database driver (DBAPI), not SQLAlchemy itself.* https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/errors.html#operationalerror

```
def exec_query(eng,db_user,db_pw,query):
    conn = eng.connect()
        try:
            conn.execute(query)
            conn.close()
            print('Connection closed.')
        except exc.DBAPIError as e:
            if e.connection_invalidated:
                print("Connection was invalidated!")
                exec_query(eng,db_user,db_pw,query)
```

Even in a try except block, `e.connection_invalidated` returns true every time when running the docker image.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apk add postgresql-dev 
RUN apk add build-base
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r req.txt
EXPOSE 80
ENV NAME weekly_insert
CMD ["python", "script.py"]
```

sqlalchemy version is 1.3.5 and have set the memory available to the docker engine to 7 G.B.
Any help fixing the DBAPI issue is appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be relayed to the database connection, which you did not show us.

Comment: The code you show should probably `raise` the exception again if it's not the case it wants to retry.  That might help see a problem closer to the time it actually happens.